# How to mouse drag/click and hold in puppeteer using XY coords

Tags: puppeteer, mouseevent, mouse

I know how to click using XY coords,

```
document.elementFromPoint(100, 100).click();
```

for example. This works perfectly, but I need something that can drag my mouse between two XY coords.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772472/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-puppeteer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a drag and drop action in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772472/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-puppeteer)