# How to emulate swipe on puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer and browser automation as a whole. I'd like to emulate a swiping event. I've done a lot of research, I don't event know if it's event possible, I read the puppeteer documentation but would still not find any useful help.

I tried using Webapi dispatchEvent
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent
but I get the **isTrusted : false** so it's not working on the target website. I learnt puppeteer is able to bypass that like this, hence I'd like to do the swiping with puppeteer.

[image]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is rather broad. What page are you working with and where's your code so far? Have you tried [How to simulate a drag and drop action in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772472/how-to-simulate-a-drag-and-drop-action-in-puppeteer)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, hope it helps

```
const element = await page.$('.selector');
const elboundingBox = await element.boundingBox();
const xWidth = targetboundingBox.width / 2;
const yHeight = targetboundingBox.height / 2;

await page.mouse.move( elboundingBox.x + xWidth, elboundingBox.y + xHeight);
await page.mouse.down();
await page.mouse.move(newTargetLeft, newTargetTop, { steps: 1 });
await page.mouse.up();
```

Replace newTargetLeft and newTargetTop with your new x and y positions respectively. Changing the steps sets the how immediate the move should occur

Comment: It was quite difficult understanding the variables in the code but at last it helped. I now have what I wanted. Thanks